# Kafka consumer failed to rebalance with phpClient using gRPC connection

Tags: php, apache-kafka, grpc

I have 30 php queue consumer with 60 partitions of `rdkafka`.

Consumer will make grpc connection to `PythonServer` from `PhpClient`, this will work fine (takes long time to consume) till restart of the queue.

Once the consumer queue restarted, queue will **fail to assign consumer** to the partitions. Immediately after stopping `phpClient`(queue will be running) from using `grpc` and `rebalancing` will be fine.
Any lead or help to debug and find why kafka is not able to rebalance?
 Thanks in advance.

**Configurations:**

```
kafka - 1.3.5
php-7.2.3
python-3.7
```